# React undefined this in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

someone can explain to me why this value in the renderInput function is undefined. I browse the code and everything looks good.

Here is error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderError' of undefined
```

This is my component AddCatalog. When it calls console.log(this) in renderInput, this returns me undefinded

```
import React, {PropTypes} from "react";
    import {Field, reduxForm} from "redux-form";
    //
    class AddCatalog extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.renderError = this.renderError.bind(this);
        }
        renderError({error, touched}) {
            alert("asds");
            if (touched && error) {
                return <div className="red">{error}</div>;
            }
        }
        renderInput({input, label, meta}) {
            return (
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>{label}</label>
                    <input {...input} className="form-control" autoComplete="off" />
                    {this.renderError}
                </div>
            );
        }
        onSubmit(formValues) {
            console.log(formValues);
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
                    <div className="row paddingLR30 container-fluid">
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <h2>Dane placówki</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-3">
                            <Field label="Nazwa placówki*" name="name_kindergarten" component={this.renderInput} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            );
        }
    }

    const validate = (formValues) => {
        const errors = {};
        if (!formValues.name_kindergarten) {
            errors.name_kindergarten = "Musisz podać nazwę przedszkola";
        }
        return errors;
    };

    export default reduxForm({
        form: "simple",
        validate
    })(AddCatalog);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because renderInput is not called in the context of the component - you forgot to [bind](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) it to `this` in the constructor the way you did with `renderError`.

Comment: Yep forgot this.renderInput = this.renderInput.bind(this);

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling this function like `this.renderError()`  , you gave a pointer like `this.renderError`.

present code :

```
 renderInput({input, label, meta}) {
        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>{label}</label>
                <input {...input} className="form-control" autoComplete="off" />
                {this.renderError}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

correct code :

```
 renderInput({input, label, meta}) {
        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>{label}</label>
                <input {...input} className="form-control" autoComplete="off" />
                {this.renderError()}
            </div>
        );
    }
```